# Как распознать элемент иерархической структуры по клику и достать из него данные

Tags: reactjs

Имеется иерархическая структура данных Контейнер–Ряд–Ячейка.
На уровнях Контейнер и Ряд имеются только индексы. Практически значимые данные находятся на уровне Ячейка. Данные поставляются в формате JSON и имеют следующую структуру:

```js
[{ pillar: № стеллажа, 
   data: [ { shelf: № полки, 
             data: [ { seat: № места, 
                       data: { busy: false//true, 
                               size: 1/2; 
                               status: "string"; 
                               model: "string"
                              } 
                     },...
                   ]
           },... 
         ]
 },...
]
```

Для отображения иерархии создаю три React-компонента:

```js
    class PillarListItem extends Component {

      render () {
        const {pillar, showMachine} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="machines-pillar">
              <table className="pillar">
                <caption>
                  Стеллаж {pillar.pillar}
                </caption>
                <tbody>
               {
                 pillar.data.map((s , index) => {
                   return <ShelfListItem
                      key = {s.shelf}
                     shelf={s}
                     showShelfMachine = {() => showMachine(s)}
                   />
                 })
               }
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        )
      }
    }

    class ShelfListItem extends Component {

      render () {
        const {shelf, showShelfMachine} = this.props;

        return (
         <tr>
             {
               shelf.data.map((m , index) => {
                 return <PlaceListItem
                    key = {m.seat}
                   seat={m}
                   showPlaceMachine = {() => showShelfMachine(m)}
                 />
               })
             }
         </tr>
        )
      }
    }

    class PlaceListItem extends Component {

      render () {
        const {seat, showPlaceMachine} = this.props;

        if (seat.data.busy) {
          return (
            <td className={seat.data.status} colSpan={seat.data.size} onClick={showPlaceMachine}>{seat.data.id}</td>
          )
        } else {
          return (
            <td className={seat.data.status} colSpan={seat.data.size}>{seat.data.model}</td>
          )
        }
      }
    }
```

Отображение иерархической структуры оформляю следующим вызовом:

```js
class Pillars extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      setterMachines: gon.setterMachines,
      selectedMachine: null
    }
  }

  showPillarHandler = (machine) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedMachine: machine.data
    })
  }

  tooglePopup = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedMachine: null
    })
  }

  render () {
    const {selectedMachine, setterMachines} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container-machines">           
        {
          setterMachines.map((p,index) => {
            return <PillarListItem
              key = {p.pillar}
              pillar={p}
              showMachine = {() => this.showPillarHandler(p.data[1].data[1])}
            />
          })
        }
        
        {selectedMachine &&
          <MachineShow toogle={this.tooglePopup} machine={selectedMachine}/>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Стоит задача в получении расшифровки с уровня Ячейки при клике на неё.

Проблема. Как программно получить индексы Ряда и Ячейки для строки кода 
**this.showPillarHandler(p.data[индекс Ряда].data[индекс Ячейки])** ?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать каррирование и изменить функцию **showPillarHandler** что бы она выглядела в следующий способ:

```
  showPillarHandler = pillarIndex => shelfIndex => seatIndex => event => {
    const { setterMachines } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      selectedMachine:
        setterMachines[pillarIndex]["data"][shelfIndex]["data"][seatIndex]
    });
  };
```

При каждом `.map()` на 3 уровнях тогда нужно извлекать `index` и вызывать showPillarHandler передавая нужный индекс, как например в `PlaceListItem`

```
{setterMachines.map((p, index) => {
  return (
    // 1-ый уровень, здесь индекс является индексом полки (при вызове, он задаст pillarIndex)
    <PillarListItem
      key={p.pillar}
      pillar={p}
      showMachine={this.showPillarHandler(index)}
    />
  );
 })}
```

*Примечание*
Последний уровень - 4ый, он вызовется автоматически если в глубине дерева компонентов привязать его к какому-либо действию, например `onClick={[название]}`

[Пример на CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7okl3n5mox)